# Send commands serially with delay between commands

Tags: serial-communication

I've got the list of commands, it just takes them from a treeview. The treeview has three columns (line number, cmd, and delay).

I know how to send the commands serially,  but I dont know how to implement the delay wanted, then send the next command. But it also needs to be able to pause and stop whenever a button is pushed. So first line is (1,50, 2).

When the start button is pushed, it would send the cmd "50" then wait 2 seconds before going to the next line. If I hit pause, then resume it needs to pick up where it left off, or hitting stop to stop it completely. I am writing in python. Any ideas on how to achieve this?

The question is how to put this in a queue of some sorts,  go through the queue reading each line,  sending the command,  waiting the time specified, then going to the next item in the queue.

**Note** : I need to be able to pause and/or stop this with a push of a button.

Comment: Could you please give some more context, what kind of tools you are working with. `serial-communication` is not very specific.

Comment: This is on a raspberry pi. I can easily send single commands,  but I need for it to go through the tuples and send each based of the delay and have to be able to pause/resume or stop it